# What is the difference between coding and scripting?

Tags: python

I don't have a background in computer science. I've only ever done c and python projects and those too were used in a general way.

I had an interview for a data analyst position and I was asked this question. This entire time I thought coding, scripting and programming were all the same.

Code is something you put onto a script to make a program.
What is the difference?

Comment: This question would likely make a better google search, unless you have found answers that require much more specific clarification

Comment: coding is a more general term.  When you write a script, you are coding.  But there are forms of coding that are not scripting.  They are imprecise terms, however.

Comment: Google "scripting language", and note that many languages like C++ are not scripting languages.  Scripting is a subset of coding.

Comment: The question (yours, not the interviewer's) is fair but I believe it's on the wrong website.

Answer (score 0):

Via https://skillcrush.com/2012/09/21/coding-vs-scripting/ : "Think of coding as an umbrella term and scripting as one type of coding", "Scripting is code used to automate processes that would otherwise need to be executed step-by-step by a web developer. Where different kinds of coding languages (such as markup languages like HTML and CSS) are used to tell computers how to display a website, scripting languages are used to give instructions to programs (like websites) that are running on a computer."

While this is the technical definition of the difference between these two, they are often used interchangeably.

Comment: I disagree with Skillcrush's definition, but scripting is a fuzzy term.  JavaScript is a scripting language but does not automate processes the way they describe it.   A person can't manually carry out its actions in a web browser.

Comment: @DaveS I see where you're coming from. The two don't really have concrete definitions and I think it's a strange question for a job interview.

Comment: @DaveS I see where you're coming from too but I think it's a reasonable simplification and that the spirit of their definition is sound.

Comment: @DaveS Found this too, might be a better definition "difference between the two is that scripting languages do not require the compilation step and are rather interpreted. For example, normally, a C program needs to be compiled before running whereas normally, a scripting language like JavaScript or PHP need not be compiled."

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - yes, I suppose as a verb "scripting" is most often used to mean automating some task, like in a linux cron job or Windows PowerShell script.  theo - yes, I think of scripting as "coding using a scripting language" but that's just me  :)